# Android fatal exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Delete not supported

Tags: android

Exception after the update my code to SDK 29.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Delete not supported
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:167)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.delete(ContentProviderNative.java:547)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:1691)
        at com.ashomok.cropimagelib.ScanFragment.getBitmap(ScanFragment.java:84)
```

When I call

```
getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
```

another code update

```
@Override
public void startGalleryChooser() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.select_photo)),
                GALLERY_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.select_photo)),
                GALLERY_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

How can I deal with this exception with backward code compatibility?

I have permission granted:

```
Manifest.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS
```

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Add this permission also

Comment: Have you solve this?